# ValueError exception doesn't do anything

Tags: python, exception

I have made a script that includes an exception for ValueError, however when the exception does not run when there is a ValueError

[Value Error Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiQnK.png)

[What happens when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc5ub.png)

Comment: Please include your code and any errors as text, not images. Thanks!

Comment: You should include your code in the question, in a code block that starts and end with ```. Not as a jpg image.

Comment: The line that raises the error is outside of the "try" block that would catch it.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that raises the "ValueError" exception should be inside the `try except` block. In this case the function that raise the exception is `int()` because you try to convert a letter 'e' to an integer.

So you should do something like this:

```
try:
 ans = int(input("Answer:")) # <--- this raises the exception
 do_something()
except ValueError:
 print("This is raised if the argument of int() function is a string")
```

Answer (score -1):

As shown in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#conditional_catch-blocks) MDN Doc you should use the exceprionVar parameter into the catch block and then check if (exceptionVar instanceof ValueError)

Comment: He is asking a solution for python, not for javascript.